# Assign a user defined vector to a boost::qvm::vec

Tags: boost

I have a Vector:

```
struct vector { double coord[3]; };
```

I can do:

```
Vector v = q; // q is a qvm::vec
```

But how to do : `q = v;`?

The only way I found is to do `qvm::assign (q, v);`.  Otherwise the compiler tells me:

```
no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type Vector*.
```

I followed the documentation to define a trait ([docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/qvm/doc/quaternions_vectors_matrices.html)).  It is probably what allows the assignment `v = q` to work.

**How to do `q = v`?** (if at all possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `assign` call is the approach to take (although you can use `convert_to<T>` as well).

The reason is implicitly given as part of the [FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/qvm/doc/questions_and_answers.html):

[image]

Exactly the same reasoning goes for `operator=` which can, also, only be declared inside the type itself.

You could extend the interface by inheriting, but that removes the POD-ness, which kind of defeats the purpose of using QVM (which is to avoid overhead).